# How to implement define-type and type-case in Racket using macros?

Tags: macros, racket, plai

define-type and type-case are provided in plai scheme, but for some reason they are not present in typed/racket. I want to implement these constructs in racket using macros.

I want to create a macro "def-user-type" following is the syntax I want to use

```
    (def-user-type Shape
      [Rectangle ((l Number) (b Number))]
      [Circle    ((r radius))]
      [Blah      (())])
```

And it should roughly behave as following

```
    (define-type Shape (U Rectangle Circle Blah))
    (struct: Rectangle ([l : Number] [b Number]))
    (struct: Circle ([r : Number]))
    (struct: Blah ())
```

This is what I have achieved so far. It is incorrect and the error message given by racket compiler is not helping either.

```
#lang typed/racket
(define-syntax define-user-type
  (syntax-rules()
    [(define-user-type type-name
       [sub-type ((field-name type) ...)]
       ...)
     ((define-type type-name (U sub-type ...))
     (struct: sub-type ([field-name : type] ...))
     ...)]))
```

Please guide me.
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be asking more than one question.

First, Typed Racket has a `define-type` but it's probably a little different from the version in `#lang plai`. You can see the implementations of plai's `define-type` and `type-case` [here](https://github.com/racket/plai/blob/96c8807a2acde9249f124498e46650223a47e24a/plai-lib/datatype.rkt#L348).

Second, there are a couple of problems with your macro.

1. The right-hand side of your `syntax-rules` clause is applying the result of `define-type` as a function, which won't work. Try using a `begin` to combine the expressions.
2. Your use of your `def-user-type` macro is not following the definition. The definition requires zero or more `(field-name type)` pairs, but in `Blah` you give `()`, which is not a pair.
3. `radius` is an undefined type

Here is a version of your macro with the suggested changes:

```
#lang typed/racket

(define-syntax def-user-type
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ type-name [sub-type ((field-name type) ...)] ...)
     (begin
       (define-type type-name (U sub-type ...))
       (struct: sub-type ([field-name : type] ...)) ...)]))

(def-user-type Shape
  [Rectangle ((l Number) (b Number))]
  [Circle    ((r Number))]
  [Blah      ()])
```

And here is an example that uses a `Rectangle` as a `Shape`:

```
> ((λ: ([x : Shape]) x) (Rectangle 1 2))
- : Shape
#<Rectangle>
```